# DataTable won't initialize properly?

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, datatables

I have created search functionality on my website, and upon entering search criteria in a text box and clicking the "Search" button, a table of records from my Postgres database successfully loads beneath my search bar. However, I want this table to be a DataTable, but this doesn't seem to be working - the table, while still containing the records from my database, also displays the text "No data available" at the bottom of the table, and the sort indicator that usually appears in the table headers is now placed in the bottom row and is not functional 
[image]

I am not sure how else to make this work. I tried moving the line to initialize the table within $(document).ready, however when I do this, the table just appears as a normal table, I suppose because the table wasn't loaded when the page first loaded. This is driving me crazy! If anyone has any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, and how to properly initialize the DataTable it would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: Finally got it working! I realised that I didn't have tbody tags within my table, I didn't realise that would cause the DataTable not to initialize properly.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the "No data available in table message in your screenshot" ?

Comment: @Umashankar-Das I want to remove the message, but the problem is also that the DataTable isn't loading properly (notice how the sort options aren't visible on the table headings, etc.).

Comment: @ellenmichellen Don't edit the question with the answer, post the answer as an actual answer, or delete the question (I think adding an answer would be the best solution so if another user has this issue they can resolve it)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you really need, but, it sounds like you dont want the no data available in table message.
I'm assuming you're using ajax to retrieve data. so, when you get a success, with records available. just pick that element and set display:none to it.

Comment: I'm using PHP to retrieve data, and my problem is that the DataTable isn't initializing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working! I realised that I didn't have tbody tags within my table, and that was why my DataTable wasn't initializing properly.